# Use of LaTEX in Word

Tags: microsoft-word, latex

I would like to use LaTEX in Word, as described here:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/murrays/2017/07/30/latex-math-in-office/

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Linear-format-equations-using-UnicodeMath-and-LaTeX-in-Word-2e00618d-b1fd-49d8-8cb4-8d17f25754f8?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US

However, I simply cannot find this functionality in my Word version (16.9). I attached a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K0O5V.png) of how my Word looks like. I would really appreciate any help.